# How to have create an anonymous interface implementation in my Kotlin class and use it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, interface, kotlin

How can I have something like this java code in Kotlin?
Even the IDE does not convert it to Kotlin perfectly!

```
/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

I tried using `inner class` but then I was not able to use it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to LocalService
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're creating an anonymous class here. In Kotlin, these are [object expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html):

```
val connection = object: ServiceConnection {
    override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName, service: IBinder) { 
        //Something to do
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(arg0: ComponentName) {
        //Something to do
    }
}
```